# Vue + MQTT.js: Uncaught ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mqtt.js

Uncaught ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined
at node_modules/mqtt/node_modules/mqtt-packet/constants.js

my_mqtt.js

```js
import { connect } from "mqtt" 

var options = {
    host: 'host',
    port: 8883,
    protocol: 'mqtts',
    username: 'username',
    password: 'password'
}

// initialize the MQTT client
export const client = connect(options);

// setup the callbacks
client.on('connect', function () {
    console.log('Connected');
});

client.on('error', function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});

client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
    // called each time a message is received
    console.log('Received message:', topic, message.toString());
});

// subscribe to topic 'my/test/topic'
client.subscribe('my/test/topic');

// publish message 'Hello' to topic 'my/test/topic'
client.publish('my/test/topic', 'Hello');
```

App.vue

```js
<script>
  import { client } from './my_mqtt';

  export default {
    name: 'App',
    mqtt: client
  }

</script>

<template>
  <div id="app">
    <router-link to="/"> Go to home </router-link>
    <router-link to="/login"> Login </router-link>
    <router-link to="/register"> Register </router-link>
    <router-link to="/olist"> OList </router-link>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>

    <router-view>

    </router-view>
  </div>
</template>
```

I have tried npm i buffer. I don't have any npm vulnerabilities.

I want to run the MQTT client in the background of the client and pub/sub as the user cycles through the routes. Please let me know what the problem is. Thank you!

Comment: have you read [the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt#browser)

Comment: Yes I have. I followed all the webpack instructions to no avail.

Comment: it just seems odd you're using mqtts protocol, since (unless I'm reading it wrong) you can only use ws or wss URL's in the browser - please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: perhaps [this mqtt library issue](https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js/issues/1338) is the same as yours?